# Global Variables PHP

Tags: php, function, global-variables

I have some problems with PHP global variables.

can i define global variables in the function and use that in another function?

can i Define global variables in another global variables and use second global variable?

can i define global variables in a function, and use this function in another functions?

how about this question?

```
global $y; // $y = 5

$x = 10 * $y; // $x = 50

function numbers() {

    global $x;

    echo $x; // $x = 0;

}
```

Comment: `global $y; // $y = 5` Through Magic?

Comment: `$x = 10 * $y; // $x = 50` No. More like **0**

Comment: You should avoid using global variables.. They are not recommended in big apps as they can create really hard to find bugs

Comment: @MateiMihai If do not use globals, what should we do?

Comment: You should pass those variables as parameters..

Comment: @HankyPanky $y is defined another place.

Answer (score -1):

Please find a nice article on Global variables in php - It will tell you about various global variables that exist in Php Language and how to use and access these variables and their purpose.

Reference : https://www.w3elearners.com/php/global-variables/